# INNO SETUP : Compilation restriction

Tags: inno-setup

I Would like to create a constant, and then, adding files or not in setupfile case constant is set On Or Off

example :

```
#define ForLS "0"
[Files]
;Only for LS :
If (ForLS=="1")
{
    Source: D:\Exec\Starter.exe; DestDir: {app}\Starter; Flags: ignoreversion
    Source: D:\Exec\M2.exe; DestDir: {app}\M54; Flags: ignoreversion
}
;For All
Source: D:\Exec\M1.exe; DestDir: {app}\Starter; Flags: ignoreversion`
```

The reason is that for example M2 is heavy (10Mo) and not necessary for everybody

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the define itself, include source whether it is defined or not:

```
;#define ForLS // remove ';' to define

..

[Files]
#ifdef ForLS
Source: D:\Exec\Starter.exe; DestDir: {app}\Starter; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: D:\Exec\M2.exe; DestDir: {app}\M54; Flags: ignoreversion
#endif
Source: D:\Exec\M1.exe; DestDir: {app}\Starter; Flags: ignoreversion`
```

Comment: +1, or you can call the compiler from command line [`using /d parameter`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/topic_isppcc.htm).